# GIT: commit specific commits in same branch

Tags: git, branch, commit, squash

I'd like to squash some specific commits in my local branch.
All the commits are already on remote branch.

My case is the following :

BranchA:

- commit1
- commit2
- commit3
- commit4
- commit5

Commits to squash :  commit2 TO  commit4

Desired result :

- commit1
- commitSQUASH
- commit5

How can I do that with GIT ?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at interactive rebase.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+squash+old+commits